# Cmake - not creating the dynamic links

Tags: cmake, makefile

The project that I am compiling is not linking my shared object file to the main program. This can be confirmed by doing the `ldd` command on my executable and seeing it say `libba.so => not found`.

Inside my CMakeLists.txt file I have:

```
add_library(ba SHARED "/usr/local/include/libba.cpp" "/usr/local/include/libba.h")
target_link_libraries(ba (list of other libraries that link to ba))
set_target_properties(ba PROPERTIES LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES "" LINK_FLAGS "${NO_UNDEFINED}")
add_executable(run "/usr/local/main/run.cpp")
target_link_libraries(run ba)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ldd` reports what the *run-time* linker can find.

If you see `libba.so` in the output it means the binary **is** linked to the library.

The "not found" means the *run-time* linker can't find that library (i.e. you don't have it installed in a normal system location).

So you can either install your library to a system location, configure your run-time linker to know about your custom location, link your application statically, or use an `rpath` in your binary to have it give the run-time linker additional places to look for just itself.